# Speed up interaction between excel an word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have word macro which scolls through an excel sheet, 
[image: Excel]

As seen it has several rows(112) where there is only 1 row that is to be performed action on, the one with info in the WP column and no info in the LS column.

So basically what my code does is to use the information in that row and put it into custom variables in my template word file and then save the wordfile with the name LSXXXX( This name is later written back to excel). The LS XXXX file can be seen below:

[image: LS FILE]

In addition some of the information needed to template comes from a another word file(docOut) custom properties an this can been seen below as well:
[image: dokUt]

The code works, but its extremly slow. I have added code to check if the excel is open by other users, screenupdating is set to false.

Any idea how i can speed up my code? If i use reference to excel library, that means that every user that uses my library  needs to add the reference to it by themselves, and hence early binding is not really practical.

Below is snippets from my code:

```
 Dim i As Integer
Dim oXLApp  As Object
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")


Dim xlapp As Object
'~~> Hide Excel
oXLApp.Visible = False



Dim temp As Variant


'Dictionary with all types
Set temp = getTypes(Settings.userNameFile)


projectnumber = GUI.ComboBoxProjectnumberLogScheme.Value
initGUI.closeGUI

dokut = FileHandling.getDocOutName(projectnumber)
On Error Resume Next

 If Not FileHandling.openDocument(dokut) Then
     MSG = MsgBox("Doc out does not exist, create it?", vbYesNo, "Creater")
    'ask if the user really knows what he is doing...
    If MSG = vbYes Then

       If Not FileHandling.createDocument(projectnumber) Then
            MsgBox "Failed to create document, sorry mate"
            GoTo Terminate:
        End If

    Else
       GoTo Terminate:
    End If
End If

tittel = Documents(dokut).CustomDocumentProperties("ProsjektTittel")

If tittel = "" Then
    ' Promt user to input title
     tittel = InputBox("Type the project title")
    'ask if the user really knows what he is doing...
    If tittel = "" Then
        GoTo Terminate:
    Else
        Call createCustomDocumentProperty(dokut, "ProsjektTittel", tittel, msoPropertyTypeString)
    End If
End If

subject = "Logg skjema"
company = Documents(dokut).CustomDocumentProperties("_Company")
myKeywords = Documents(dokut).CustomDocumentProperties("_Keywords")
avsender = temp(Environ$("Username"))
ceo = Documents(dokut).CustomDocumentProperties("CEO")
customer = Documents(dokut).CustomDocumentProperties("Customer")

If customer = "" Or customer = "Customer" Then
    ' Promt user to input title
     customer = InputBox("Type the name of the customer")
    'ask if the user really knows what he is doing...
    If customer = "" Then
        GoTo Terminate:
    Else
        Call createCustomDocumentProperty(dokut, "Customer", customer, msoPropertyTypeString)
    End If
End If


myFileName = Settings.projectFolder & projectnumber & "\" & Settings.partsList

If Dir(myFileName) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The parts list does not exist, manually copy it over please or rename it to : " & vbNewLine & myFileName
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim Ret

Ret = LogScheme.IsWorkBookOpen(myFileName)

If Ret = True Then
    MsgBox "Partslist is open, close it and try again"
    GoTo Terminate
End If

Set xlapp = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(myFileName) 'Filename:=file-path, ReadOnly:=True
xlapp.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'oXLApp.Visible = False


numofrows = LogScheme.firstBlankRow(xlapp)
columnWp = LogScheme.getColumn("WP", xlapp)
columnDrawing = LogScheme.getColumn("Drawing", xlapp)
columnQuantity = LogScheme.getColumn("Quantity", xlapp)
columnCommonName = LogScheme.getColumn("Common", xlapp)
columnMaterial = LogScheme.getColumn("Material", xlapp)
columnMaterialCertificate = LogScheme.getColumn("Certificate", xlapp)
columnCustomerRequirements = LogScheme.getColumn("Customer", xlapp)
columnMOM = LogScheme.getColumn("MOM", xlapp)
columnSerie = LogScheme.getColumn("Serie", xlapp)
columnLogSchema = LogScheme.getColumn("LS", xlapp)
columnSupplierMaterial = LogScheme.getColumn("Location", xlapp)
columnRevision = LogScheme.getColumn("Revision", xlapp)

If numofrows < 3 Or IsEmpty(numofrows) Then
    MsgBox "The partslist is empty, no logscheme can be produced"
    GoTo Terminate
End If

j = 0
ProgressBar.Show vbModeless
For i = 3 To numofrows
    sPercentage = (i / numofrows) * 100
    ProgressBar.progress (sPercentage)
    If Not IsEmpty(xlapp.sheets("List").Cells(i, columnWp).Value) And IsEmpty(xlapp.sheets("List").Cells(i, columnLogSchema).Value) Then
        j = j + 1
        Call main.NewFile(3, projectnumber, xlapp.sheets("List").Cells(i, columnCommonName).Value, xlapp.sheets("List").Cells(i, columnDrawing).Value, avsender)
        docTemplate = ActiveDocument.Name

        'get properties from excel
        Documents(docTemplate).CustomDocumentProperties("WP") = xlapp.sheets("List").Cells(i, columnWp).Value
```

some code, then cleaning up:

```
 Unload ProgressBar

MsgBox "Created " & j & "New Log Schemes"

xlapp.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
xlapp.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
xlapp.Quit
Set xlapp = Nothing
Set oXLApp = Nothing

' Do all on the doc out document.....
dokut = FileHandling.getDocOutName(projectnumber)

If FileHandling.openDocument(dokut) Then
    Call initGUI.closeGUI
    Call searchAll("LS")
Else
    MsgBox "Did not find any dokument with that number, sorry mate."
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Documents(dokut).Activate
Documents(dokut).Save

Terminate:
    initGUI.closeGUI
    Exit Sub
```

The code uses this code to check if the excel file is open by another user:

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

and this function to find first empty row/last row+1:

```
Function firstBlankRow(ByRef xlapp) As Long
'returns the row # of the row after the last used row
With xlapp.sheets("List")
    firstBlankRow = .Range("A1").Offset(.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Get rid of the loop and use `AutoFilter()` with `SpecialCells()`

Comment: I would have advise to put your useful rows in an array rather than loop directly on the worksheet, but not sure it'll be much more time efficient...
Do you have time stamps for different parts of your code? I use a custom progress bar that create a time table that can be used to know which part of code is time consuming. Let me know if you are interested!

Comment: @R3uK If i could use your time code to check the problem it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use it, place this in your code :

```
UpdateProg %value, True_or_False
```

**%value** : is your displayed percentage of progress, and will be your "ID" with timings
**True_or_False** : True to add this to time table, False to only update progress bar

Here is the form used to launch the master macro, show progress, and tell you in how much time the whole thing has been done.
[ZIP with form and code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18891649/Launcher_clean.zip)
The only thing that you need to do is to **change MasterMacro with the name of your main procedure**. (You won't miss it in the code of form)

Here is the code to put in a module, that is the most useful functions used with the Launcher form.

```
Public Progression As Double
Public StarTTime As Double

Sub ClickToLaunch()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Launcher.Show
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateProg(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal Timing As Boolean)
    If Value <> 0 Then
    Else
        StarTTime = Timer
    End If

    Launcher.Image_barre.Width = Value * 1.5
    Launcher.Label_barre.Caption = Format(Value, "##0,0") & "%"
    DoEvents

If Timing Then
    TimT(0, UBound(TimT, 2)) = Value
    TimT(1, UBound(TimT, 2)) = Timer - StarTTime
    TimT(2, UBound(TimT, 2)) = Timer - TimT(1, UBound(TimT, 2) - 1) - StarTTime
    ReDim Preserve TimT(UBound(TimT, 1), UBound(TimT, 2) + 1)
Else
End If

End Sub


Public Sub Print2D_Array(ByVal ArrayT As Variant, ByVal SheetName As String)

DeleteAndAddSheet SheetName

For I = LBound(ArrayT, 1) To UBound(ArrayT, 1)
    For j = LBound(ArrayT, 2) To UBound(ArrayT, 2)
      Sheets(SheetName).Cells(I + 1, j + 1) = ArrayT(I, j)
    Next j
Next I


End Sub


Public Function DeleteAndAddSheet(ByVal SheetName As String) As Worksheet

For Each aShe In Sheets
    If aShe.Name <> SheetName Then
    Else
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        aShe.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next aShe

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = SheetName

Set DeleteAndAddSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

End Function
```

Comment: @skatun Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to R3Uk, I managed to solve the perfomance issue. I made a GUI with checkboxes at each event. And it turn out that the problem was finding the column number that took forever, this was a a small mistake in my code:

```
    Public Function getColumn(header As String, ByRef xlApp) As Long
        Dim rng1 As Object
        With xlApp.Sheets("List")
           ' was .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count))
            Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count))
            If rng1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("ERROR: Range object is empty.")
            getColumn = -1
            Exit Function
            End If
            For Each m In rng1
            If InStr(UCase(CStr(m)), UCase(header)) Then
            getColumn = m.Column
            Exit Function
            End If
            Next m
            MsgBox "Column " & header & " does not exist, Typo??", vbCritical
            getColumn = -1
       End With
    End Function
```

Seemed like that it search for the text to match the column in the whole sheet instead of the header row, and hence it took more than 1 minute to find all the column indexes. I also attached my code to populate the GUI checkboxes in case someones fins it useful, it helped me a lot:)

```
Sub DebuggerGUI(CheckBoxNumber, stateMy As Boolean, deltaTime, Optional ByVal   numberLS As Integer = -1)

Dim contr As control
Dim logText As String
logText = ""

For Each contr In LS.Controls
    If TypeName(contr) = "CheckBox" And InStr(contr.name, CheckBoxNumber) Then
        contr.Value = stateMy

        If Not numberLS = -1 Then
            logText = " - Number of LS created: " & CStr(numberLS)
        End If
        contr.Caption = contr.Caption & deltaTime & logText
        LS.Hide
        LS.Show vbModeless
    End If
Next


End Sub
```